# Anyway of using before time function and equal to?

Tags: android

i am using the code below:

```
endTimeEntryCal2.before(addTimeEntryCale)
```

to check if user set time is before current time but i also want it to be before or equal to is there anyway of doing this here eg something like before=();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
endTimeEntryCal2.compareTo(addTimeEntryCale) <= 0
```

> [int compareTo(Calendar anotherCalendar)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo%28java.util.Calendar%29)
>
> Compares the times of the two Calendar, which represent the
>   milliseconds from the January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT (Gregorian).
>   Parameters anotherCalendar    another calendar that this one is compared with
>
> ***Returns:***
>   0 if the times of the two Calendars are equal,
>   -1 if the time of this Calendar is before the other one
>   1 if the time of this Calendar is after the other one.

Comment: Thanks i think this should do :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        long mills = cal.getTimeInMillis(); 
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        int x = (mills <= currentTime)?0:1; 

                    if(x == 1)
                     {
                      // Time Available
                      }else 
                          {
                       //Time passed
                          }
```